# AngularJs pass item property in ng-repeat to controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

I need to pass an item property in an ng-repeat to the controller like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="feed in feeds | filter:customFilter(feed,feed.publishedDate) ">
```

Sending feed.publishedDate like this does't work, how should I do that?

Or could I access this property in the controller? item.publishedDate doesn;t work...
I need it to compare it with the actual time and filter the news by last hour, last 4 hours, ...

```
$scope.customFilter = function (item, publishedDate) {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    if($scope.timeinterval==1){
             ....
    }
```

Comment: That's not how you use filters in views, it should be:

    <li ng-repeat="feed in feeds | customFilter: feed, feed.publishedDate "> 

Not sure if this solves your parameter problem though...

Comment: No.. but thanks! My filter is in a controller

Comment: Why not write a .filter() module?

Comment: I would still have the same problem, I need a property of each element in the ng-repeat (feed.publishedDate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter function should return a predicate:

Controller:

```
$scope.cutoffDate= new Date();

$scope.customFilter = function(cutoffDate) {

    return function(feed){
        return feed.publishedDate <= cutoffDate;
    };
};
```

View:

```
ng-repeat="feed in feeds | filter:customFilter(cutoffDate)"
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/PmQmE/2/)</kbd>

Comment: The problem is check that condition, for that I need the publishedDate that is in feed.publishedDate, and filter:customFilter(feed.publishedDate)  doen't work

Comment: The feed is passed to the predicate so you can check it there. I'll amend the example.

Comment: That was my first idea, but feed.publishedDate doesn't work :S

Comment: item.publishedDate <= new Date(); or item.publishedDate >= new Date(); is always false

Comment: if (item.publishedDate) always false too

Comment: Do you mean? ng-repeat="feed in feeds | filter:customFilter(feed)" ?? Still not working

Comment: but feed.publishedDate now has something :)

Comment: You don't need to pass the feed in the call to the customFilter in the view.

Comment: You are right, but it doesn't really matter in this case. Anyway I think that now it's working, I had to format the date: new Date(feed.publishedDate).  I will see it more in detail tomorrow and tell you. Thank you very much for your help.